# Kivy app cannot be launched after first run

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy

I am trying to learn kivy. The first time I tried to run the file the GUI will come out. When I tried to run the exact same code it reports error like this... I'll need to restart Python to be able to run it again. I am using Python 2.7 and my OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

```
[DEBUG  ] [App         ] Loading kv </home/dq/my.kv>
[DEBUG  ] [App         ] kv </home/dq/my.kv> not found
[DEBUG  ] [Base        ] Create provider from mouse
[DEBUG  ] [Base        ] Create provider from probesysfs
[DEBUG  ] [ProbeSysfs  ] using probsysfs!
[DEBUG  ] [ProbeSysfs  ] found device: AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint at /dev/input/event6
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event6
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event6>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Exception in thread Thread-4:
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
     self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
     execfile(filename, namespace)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
     self.run()
File "/home/dq/untitled1.py", line 25, in <module>
     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
     v.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/mtdev.py", line 192, in _thread_run
     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 600, in run
     _device = Device(_fn)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/mtdev.py", line 192, in _thread_run
     runTouchApp()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lib/mtdev.py", line 131, in __init__
     _device = Device(_fn)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 454, in runTouchApp
     self._fd = os.open(filename, os.O_NONBLOCK | os.O_RDONLY)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lib/mtdev.py", line 131, in __init__
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/input/event6'
     self._fd = os.open(filename, os.O_NONBLOCK | os.O_RDONLY)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 325, in mainloop
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/input/event6'
     self._mainloop()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 231, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 311, in idle
     window.dispatch('on_flip')
File "_event.pyx", line 285, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:4184)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 541, in on_flip
     self.flip()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 220, in flip
     pygame.display.flip()
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

Comment: This is a curious problem, but I notice you are using pygame. Kivy 1.9 (the newest version) uses sdl2 now, and you should upgrade to this. It may be that this resolves the problem.

Comment: I notice the line [DEBUG  ] [App         ] kv </home/dq/my.kv> not found.. is that perhaps a factor? Is your kv file named correctly?